# yii2 "urlmanager" rules "conflict" issue?

Tags: yii2

### yii2 urlmanager issue.Can any one help?

http://localhost/Myapp/find/search/item?q is working.
http://localhost/Myapp/find/search/item?r this one not working.How to solve this?

Comment: show us rules of your urlmanager

Comment: but my guess would be that `r` is used as default yii get param for `route`

Comment: thanks for the replay first.yes of course,is there any solution to use query string value as r